# Xamarin Android Binding: how to use an interface from library

Tags: android, xamarin, binding

My Xamarin Android Binding project (after few duplicate methods fixed) compiles correctly.

Now i have to use an interface from library.
In Java i did this way:

```
private PCLIAE87Events btProtListener;
btProtListener = new PCLIAE87Events () {
    @Override
    public void onLibraryStarted(PCLIAE87 library) {
        btProtLibrary = library;
    }
};
```

How can i do in C#?
I have to pass this interface to a function

```
PCLIAE87.StartLibrary(this, new PCLIAE87Events())
```

but interfaces passed as method parameters do not works in C#.

Java Interface *PCLIAE87Events* in C# is binded automatically as *IPCLIAE87Events* (public interface IPCLIAE87Events : IAbstractPCLEvents, IJavaObject, IDisposable)

I tried also to create a class which implements Interface and its methods:

```
class PCLIAE87EventsImplementation : Java.Lang.Object, IPCLIAE87Events
{
    public void OnLibraryStarted(Java.Lang.Object p0)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnPOSConnected()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnPOSDisconnected()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

but i get this error

> PCLIAE87EventsImplementation is not abstract and does not override
>   abstract method onLibraryStarted(PCLIAE87) in AbstractPCLEvents

I think is related to a Xamarin Binding Error, maybe someone can suggest me where i have to check?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous class creation is not supported in C#. So you must create a class implementing this interface. As far as I can figure it should be something like:

```
class PCLIAE87EventsImplementation : PCLIAE87Events 
{
    piblic void OnLibraryStarted(PCLIAE87 library) 
    {
         btProtLibrary = library;
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to call

```
PCLIAE87Events btProtListener = new PCLIAE87EventsImplementation();
PCLIAE87.StartLibrary(this, btProtListener);
```

Comment: Thank you,i tried your solution too (please see my updated post)

Comment: Im not very sure, but try changing the parameter type to `IPCLIAE87` or try writing `onLibraryStarted` with a small `o`